# Concise conditional operator in Scala

Tags: scala, scalaz

Let me demonstrate what I expect from a conditional operator:

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
import util.Random

trait Card

class BigCard extends Card

class SmallCard extends Card

object Main extends App {
  def printCard(card: Card) {println(card.getClass.getSimpleName)}

  // Line bellow works fine, but I would prefer less verbose conditional operator (like ?: from JavaScript).
  (if (Random.nextBoolean) new BigCard else new SmallCard) |> printCard

  // I thought ScalaZ's ?| was meant to be an alternative to if. But following statement fails to compile. 
  (Random.nextBoolean ? new BigCard | new SmallCard) |> printCard
}
```

Result:

```
[error] xxx/Main.scala:15: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : SmallCard
[error]  required: BigCard
[error]   (Random.nextBoolean ? new BigCard | new SmallCard) |> printCard
[error]                                       ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

Is there some alternative to ScalaZ's ?| operator which supports subclasses (not sure about the term, or is it type widening)?

I am looking for a concise conditional operator (so manually adding types is out of question, it would end up being much longer and uglier than `if`). Can it be easily added (as in without custom macro) or does some library supplies such operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's quite easy (`implicit class` can't be declared at top level, put this into an `object` and import its contents):

```
class Cond[A](x: Boolean, value: => A) {
  def |[B >: A](other: => B) = if (x) value else other
}

implicit class CondOp(x: Boolean) {
  def ?[A](y: => A) = new Cond(x, y)
}
```

Scalaz apparently defines `def |(other: A)` instead.

The drawback (and presumably why Scalaz doesn't do it) is that it also compiles for unrelated types, since in Scala *any* two types have a common supertype: `Random.nextBoolean ? 1 | ""`. Also, for `x ? 1 | 1.0` you won't get a widening to `Double`, as you would for `if`; it returns `AnyVal` instead.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think it would be that easy. I'll test it. I thought compiler warned about widening to Any/AnyVal/AnyRef. I would add call-by-name, so it behaves more like classic if (not evaluating other branch).

Comment: Works fine, thanks :). If anyone need a lazy version (or complete example) take a look at https://gist.github.com/mnn/3ef2e1bb67a93733a7d293c0fe7e10c2.

Comment: "I thought compiler warned about widening to Any/AnyVal/AnyRef." Yes, you'll get a warning in this case (and good point about by-name, I'll edit the answer).